# Проблема с выводом элемента(двувимерного масива) что встречаеться больше одного раза

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int val = 0;
    int count = 0;
    const int max = 4;
    int arr[max][max];
    double max1 = arr[0][0];
    //Ввод элементов в массив
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
            cin >> val;
            arr[j][i] = val;
        }
    }
    //Максимальний элемент массива
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
            if (max1 < arr[i][j]) {
                max1 = arr[i][j];
            }
            
            
           
            //Нахождения элемента (max1) который встречаеться больше одного раза  
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)

            {
                for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
                {
                    if (max1 == arr[i][j])
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count > 1)
            {
               
            }
            cout << max1;
        }
       
    }
  

}
```

Comment: Сначала у меня было задания найти максимальный элемент, потом если этот элемент встречаеться больше одного раза то вывести его.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int count, size;
    cin >> size;
    int** arr = new int*[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      arr[i] = new int[size];
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++) 
      {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    int max = arr[0][0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++) 
      {
         if (max < arr[i][j]) 
         {
            max = arr[i][j];
            count = 0;
         }
         if (max == arr[i][j])
           count++;
      }
    }
    if (count > 1) cout << max;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
     delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;

}
```

Если я правильно понял условие, вам нужно вывести максимальный элемент массива, если он встречается больше 1 раза. Если решение не подходит, сформулируйте конкретнее свой вопрос

Comment: Простите, но у меня ваш код не роботает

Comment: у вас код роботает ?

Comment: Я просто ввожу массив но ничего не выходит

Comment: Да, работает по условию, которое я описал. Читайте код внимательно, вы должны вводить не только массив. Сначала размер квадратной матрицы, а затем уже ее элементы.

Comment: Я ввожу матрицу с размером 4x4, вписываю числа и в конце пишет это: Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'count' is being used without being initialized.

Comment: там где count ++

Comment: Я честно ввожу как вы скзали, но ничего не роботает.

Comment: может это Visual studion "Выкаблучиваеться" ?

Comment: Я не знаю, чем могу вам помочь. Проверил в трех разных компиляторах, везде работает.
[Компилятор](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)

Comment: а может сказать один онлайн компилятор для этого

Comment: ну где можно еще попробывать

Comment: Я оставил вам ссылку, нажмите на слово "Компилятор".

Comment: У мене еще вопрос. Смотрите у меня же получаеться массив 4x4 к примеру

Comment: у меня в задании пишет что найти макс. элемент который встречаеться больше одного раза, значит если у меня в массиве буде число 10 но оно будет одно, но если у меня будет четыре девятки то оно должно вывести 9 так как оно встречаеться больше одного раза. Как мне это сделать?